# Google Charts change color with php if statement

Tags: php, jquery, google-visualization

I would like to change individual bar colour in google charts. All data comes from db using php script.It works if I set up colour manually or as php variable with static value. But didn't work with php if statement...

```
...
while ($row = $query -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
//if ($row[value] < 0 ) {$color = 'red';} else {$color = 'green';};
$color = 'red';
echo "['$row[no]', $row[value],  '$color'],";
};
...
```

If I uncommenting line with if statement and put comment on line 3 then didn't work. But if I leave as now then works.

Comment: what is `$row[value]`? you mean `$row['value']`

Comment: It works  now should be $row['value'] in if statement. Thanks

Comment: can i make it an answer?

Comment: @LuthandoLoot yes no problem

Comment: I added it as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it seems like your issue here was that you had `$row[value]` instead of `$row['value']`